# Two-player number guessing game

Tags: c#, number-guessing-game

I created a 2-player number guessing game. Each player picks a number between 1 and 10 and closest one wins.

I'm just looking for best practices suggestions and improvements.

**Console program.cs**

```
using ClassLibrary1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] _guesses = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        const int ERROR_INPUT = 1000;
        const int ERROR_SAME = 1001;
        static int _numberOfRounds = 2;
        static Class1 _newGame;

        static List<string> _status = new List<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _newGame = new Class1();

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                PrintScores();

                PromptPlayer(Player.One);
                PromptPlayer(Player.Two);

                //both guesses are valid at this point
                //Console.Clear();
                //_status.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

                Player winner = _newGame.Play(_guesses);
                Console.WriteLine("And the winner of this round was Player {0}. The number was: {1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Player), winner), _newGame.TargetNumber);
                Console.ReadKey();
                //Setup new round
                _guesses = new int[] { 0, 0 };
                _status = new List<string>();
                _newGame.CreateNewTargetNumber();

            } while (_newGame.PlayerOneScore < _numberOfRounds && _newGame.PlayerTwoScore < _numberOfRounds);

            Console.Clear();
            PrintScores();
            _status.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

            if (_newGame.PlayerOneScore == _numberOfRounds)
                Console.WriteLine("Player One wins!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Player Two wins!");
        }

        private static void PrintScores()
        {
            _status.Add(string.Format("Player One: {0}", _newGame.PlayerOneScore));
            _status.Add(string.Format("Player Two: {0}", _newGame.PlayerTwoScore));
            _status.Add("---------");
        }

        private static void PromptPlayer(Player player)
        {
            bool isValid = false;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                _status.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

                if (_guesses[(int)player] == ERROR_INPUT)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("Player {0}, enter valid number between 1 and 10: ", Enum.GetName(typeof(Player), player));
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    isValid = GetPlayerGuess(player);
                }
                else if (_guesses[(int)player] == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("Player {0} enter your guess? ", Enum.GetName(typeof(Player), player));
                    isValid = GetPlayerGuess(player);
                }
                else if (_guesses[(int)player] == ERROR_SAME)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("Player {0}, can't use same number: ", Enum.GetName(typeof(Player), player));
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    isValid = GetPlayerGuess(player);
                }

                if (isValid)
                {
                    _status.Add(string.Format("Player {0} guess was: {1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Player), player), _guesses[(int)player]));
                    isValid = true;
                }
            } while (!isValid);

        }

        private static bool GetPlayerGuess(Player player)
        {
            string playerGuess = string.Empty;
            playerGuess = Console.ReadLine();
            int validGuess = 0;
            int.TryParse(playerGuess, out validGuess);

            if (validGuess > 0 && _guesses.Contains(validGuess))
            {
                _guesses[(int)player] = ERROR_SAME;
                return false;
            }
            else if (validGuess > 0 && validGuess <= 10)
            {
                _guesses[(int)player] = validGuess;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                _guesses[(int)player] = ERROR_INPUT;
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Class1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public enum Player
    {
        One = 0,
        Two
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public int TargetNumber { get; private set; }
        public int PlayerOneScore { get { return _scores[0]; } }
        public int PlayerTwoScore { get { return _scores[1]; } }

        private int[] _scores = new int[2] { 0, 0 };

        public Class1()
        {
            TargetNumber = new Random().Next(1, 10);
        }

        public void CreateNewTargetNumber() { TargetNumber = new Random().Next(1, 10); }

        public Player Play(int[] _guesses)
        {
            Player winner;

            int playerOneGuessInt = Convert.ToInt32(_guesses[0]);
            int playerTwoGuessInt = Convert.ToInt32(_guesses[1]);

            int playerOneDiff = Math.Abs(playerOneGuessInt - TargetNumber);
            int playerTwoDiff = Math.Abs(playerTwoGuessInt - TargetNumber);

            if (playerOneDiff == playerTwoDiff)
            {
                //tie
                //who didn't go over
                if (playerOneGuessInt < 0)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Player Two wins!");
                    _scores[1]++;
                    winner = Player.Two;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Player One wins!");
                    _scores[0]++;
                    winner = Player.One;
                }
            }
            else if (playerOneDiff < playerTwoDiff)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Player One was the closest. The number was {0}", target);
                _scores[0]++;
                winner = Player.One;
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Player Two was the closest. The number was {0}", target);
                _scores[1]++;
                winner = Player.Two;
            }

            return winner;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't change code after you've posted a question here at Code Review. That could invalidate answers, both existing (if present) and those in the making.

Answer (score 8):

I see several things that could be changed/improved...

---

You dont't have to initialize array items if they should be zeros so this:

> ```
> static int[] _guesses = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
> ```

is the same as this

```
 static int[] _guesses = new int[2];
```

---

You write a comment above those three lines:

> ```
> //Setup new round
> _guesses = new int[] { 0, 0 };
> _status = new List<string>();
> _newGame.CreateNewTargetNumber();
> ```

make it a method and the comment won't be necessary:

```
private static void SetupNewRound()
{
    _guesses = new int[2];
    _status = new List<string>();
    _newGame.CreateNewTargetNumber();
}
```

---

I think it would be a good idea to create a new `Player` class and give it some properties like:

```
class Player 
{
    public PlayerName Name { get; set; }
    public int Guesses { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

to encapsulate all those fields that hold data related to players like `_guesses`, `PlayerOneScore`, `PlayerTwoScore`, `_scores` etc. Currently player data is scattered over multiple classes and assemblies. You hold some of it in `Class1` and `_guesses` in `Program`.

Your enum then gets the name `PlayerName` and you change `_guesses` to `_players` and make it a dictionary of players:

```
Dictionary<PlayerName, Player> _players = new Players[] 
{
    Player { Name = PlayerName.One },
    Player { Name = PlayerName.Two },
}.ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
```

This change will allow you to remove lot's of code (several fields) and make your classes simpler and easier to read.

So a line like this one:

> ```
> else if (_guesses[(int)player] == 0)
> ```

would become:

```
else if (_players[playerName].Guesses == 0)
```

or instead of hard coding player names or their count in strings

> ```
> _status.Add(string.Format("Player One: {0}", _newGame.PlayerOneScore));
> ```

you'll have

```
foreach(var player in _game.Players.Values)
{
    status.Add(string.Format("Player {0}: {1}", player.Name, player.Score));
}
```

and your application will be more flexible.

---

I guess the name of `Class1` is just an accident because you gave everything else very good names ;-)

and when I see this line:

> ```
> static Class1 _newGame;
> ```

its name should probably be `Game`.

Comment: Awesome! thanks so much for taking the time to share some insights. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`if (_guesses[(int)player] == ERROR_INPUT)` and `else if (_guesses[(int)player] == ERROR_SAME)` contains four lines which are almost identical, except for the message. Instead of copy-pasting you should have moved them to a method:

```
private void WarnPlayer(string message)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write(message, Enum.GetName(typeof(Player), player));
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
}
```

---

I'd move `PromptPlayer` and `GetPlayerGuess` to a separate class instead of keeping them in `Program`.

Comment: maybe in the Player class as mention in first review?

Comment: @Rod No, that Player class should be used to store data. I can't think of a name right now, however.